# Linux: spurious "New Sink" notification with new HDMI graphics card

Tags: linux, audio, hdmi, notifications, gnome3

My machine runs Linux (Debian unstable) at home.  I recently replaced my old NVidia graphics card with a newer beast, a Radeon 5600 XT.  Part of this device is an HDMI audio controller, as evidenced here:

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT] (rev ca)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 HDMI Audio
```

I did not use an HDMI connector with my old graphics card, but I am with the new one.  I'm running Gnome 3 as my desktop.  Every time my monitor goes to sleep (DPMS standby), I get a large number of notifications of a

```
New Sink "Navi 10 HDMI Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
alsa_output.pci-0000_3_00.1.hdmi-stereo
```

clogging up my notification panel when I re-enable the monitor.  These notifications are very annoying (they detract from notification I actually *want* to receive), and I am hoping someone can help me figure out how to disable these (specifically).

Comment: Did you deal with it?  I have this problem too.

Comment: I did not, sorry.